# Is there a difference between ます and ません for sentences carrying an exclusive connotation(しか)?

Tags: usage, negation, polarity-items

> 私は野菜しか食べません。

apparently means "I only eat vegetables"? Shouldn't there be a negative connotation with the ません-ending?

If that's the case what does 私は野菜しか食べます mean?
Is there a special contextual rule with exceptions or just the term しか?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/87658/30454

Comment: Good question, hard to explain... [Does ません sometimes not negate?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73155/does-%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93-sometimes-not-negate)

Comment: Does this answer help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are good linked questions, but I think I'll try my hand at an answer.

There exist constructs and words in Japanese that either take on a different meaning, or can only be used with a negative sentence. しか is one such construct. It can *only* be used with a negative sentence. It is grammatically incorrect with a positive sentence.

For instance, ほとんど can be used in a positive sentence to mean "almost, nearly", but in a negative sentence, it means "barely".

誰も and 何も are other examples of expressions that can only be used in negative sentences.

In this case, you could think of it as "I don't eat anything except vegetables".

Comment: I see, I'm still lacking the vocabulary fundamentals.

Comment: Don't worry, it's a marathon, not a sprint. がんばってね